# Is $\int_s^t {B_u}^2 du$ independent of $ F_s$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

In order to prove that  $(B_t^4)_{t \in \mathbb{R+}}$ is a continuous semi-martingale I need to compute. $E(\int_s^t B_u^2 du |F_s)$
I was first thinking that $\int_s^t B_u^2 du$  independent of $ F_s$ but this can't be true but I can't argue why ? Could someone help me out here.
I say that it can't be true because I am given the Doob-decomposition of $(B_t^4)_{t \in \mathbb{R+}}$ as

$B_t^4=(B_t^4-6\int_0^t B_u^2 du) +6\int_0^t B_u^2 du$

and when I try to show that $(B_t^4-6\int_0^t B_u^2 du)_{t \in \mathbb{R_+}}$ is  a martinagale , for the proof to work , $\int_s^t B_u^2 du$ can't be independent of $ F_s$ because if it were , then $(B_t^4-6\int_0^t B_u^2 du)_{t \in \mathbb{R_+}}$ won't be a martingale

Comment: Since $B_u=B_s+\beta_{u-s}$ with $B_s$ $F_s$-measurable and $\beta$ some Brownian motion independent of $F_s$, this is $$\int_s^tE(B_u^2\mid F_s)du=\int_s^t(B_s^2+2E(\beta_{u-s}\mid F_s)B_s+E(\beta_{u-s}^2\mid F_s))du=\int_s^t(B_s^2+u-s)du=\cdots$$

Comment: @Did Thank you so much .